# Return two nodes as a single element

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

```
<table>
    <tr class="offMiddle bordertop">
        <td></td>
        <td><strong>12:00</strong>
        </td>
        <td>02:00</td>
        <td><div><input type="radio" value="T"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <div>should be ignored</div>
    <tr class="offMiddle">
        <td></td>
        <td>17:00</td>
        <td><strong>12:30</strong>
        </td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="offMiddle bordertop">
        <td></td>
        <td><strong>19:00</strong>
        </td>
        <td>13:30</td>
        <td><div><input type="radio" value="T"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <div>should be ignored</div>
        <tr class="offMiddle">
        <td></td>
        <td><strong>09:15</strong>
        </td>
        <td>02:00</td>
    </tr>


    <tr class="offMiddle bordertop">
        <td></td>
        <td><strong>16:00</strong>
        </td>
        <td>02:50</td>
        <td><div><input type="radio" value="T"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="offMiddle">
        <td></td>
        <td><strong>12:00</strong>
        </td>
        <td>02:00</td>
    </tr>
    <div>should be ignored</div>
</table>
```

I have a table with 6 rows. I want to return the first and second rows as a single element, as well as the third and fourth, fifth and sixth. Ideally, I would like to return each of these sections as an element containing the two rows selected.

At the moment I have:

`//table/tr[contains(@class, 'offMiddle bordertop')] | //table/tr[contains(@class, 'offMiddle bordertop')]/following-sibling::tr[contains(@class, 'offMiddle')]`

which selects the following table rows without the divs that should be ignored:

```
    <tr class="offMiddle bordertop">
        <td></td>
        <td><strong>12:00</strong>
        </td>
        <td>02:00</td>
        <td><div><input type="radio" value="T"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="offMiddle">
        <td></td>
        <td>17:00</td>
        <td><strong>12:30</strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="offMiddle bordertop">
        <td></td>
        <td><strong>19:00</strong>
        </td>
        <td>13:30</td>
        <td><div><input type="radio" value="T"></div></td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="offMiddle">
        <td></td>
        <td><strong>09:15</strong>
        </td>
        <td>02:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="offMiddle bordertop">
        <td></td>
        <td><strong>16:00</strong>
        </td>
        <td>02:50</td>
        <td><div><input type="radio" value="T"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="offMiddle">
        <td></td>
        <td><strong>12:00</strong>
        </td>
        <td>02:00</td>
    </tr>
```

But I need them to be returned something like `[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]` I want to be able to then extract data from each of these grouped elements with an expression like //tr/td/strong/text().

Is this possible?

Comment: You should show sample HTML that you'd like the XPath to select.  Keep in mind that XPath can only *select* nodes that exist in the input document -- it cannot create or rearrange nodes.  Thanks.

Comment: What environment do you use XPath in?

Comment: @kjhughes I'm only looking for the expression to select the nodes as `[(tr1, tr2), (tr3, tr4), (tr5, tr6)]` because I need to access the radio button in the odd `tr`s relative the the following sibling tr. This is why I think I need the `tr`s returned in a group.

Comment: @MathiasMüller This will be executed in selenium.

Comment: If I understand correctly now, no, that's not possible. XPath defines a result sequence without grouping result nodes in any way. Even if your expression contains `|`, this will not group elements - it will just extend the result sequence. You'd have to reach for Java, XQuery or XSLT.

Comment: Agree with @MathiasMüller, unless "*I need to access the radio button in the odd trs relative the the following sibling tr*" means you'd be ok writing this statement as a test which Selenium could apply over a range rather than asking XPath to construct a rearranged sequence/grouping.